# How to use AngularJS ng-repeat to traverse an object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I use ng-repeat to traverse an object?

Object definition:

```
map.montana = 1;
map.iowa = 2;
map.ohio = 3;
```

Directive:

```
<div ng-repeat= " place in ['montana',iowa','ohio'] track by $index">
  <div>map.place</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use bracket notation when trying to access an object property via variable:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in ['montana',iowa','ohio'] track by $index">    
    <div>{{map[place]}}</div> 
</div>
```

Controller map:

```
$scope.map = {
    montana: 1,
    iowa: 2,
    ohio: 3
}
```

And dont forget your `{{}}` to write out to the view.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add an **'** before **iowa**.

> ['montana', 'iowa', 'ohio']

As @tymeJV said don't forget `{{map[place]}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your output should be

```
<div>{{ map[place] }} </div> </div>
```